# FATAL : No Bootable medium found! System halted

Tags: linux, virtualbox, iso-image, backtrack

I just got a .iso of the linux distro Backtrack 5 R2. I set it up, using virtual box, and set it up to run using the .iso, and hard drive as a .vdi. Here's the setup:

**System:**
Base Memory: 1500 MB
Boot Order: CD/DVD-ROM, Hard Disk
Acceleration: VT-x/AMD-V, Nested Paging

**Storage:**
IDE Controller
  IDE Primary Master (CD/DVD):
BT5R2-KDE-64.iso (2.62 GB)

SATA Controller
  SATA Port 0:
Backtrack 5 R2.vdi (Normal, 8.00 GB)

Why would I be getting this error? Everything looks fine to me. And also, I'm running virtual box in a Windows 7 64bit OS.

Comment: that's strange. Does the checksum for the ISO download match?

Comment: FYI the checksum for BT5R2-GNOME-64.iso is: MD5 4864e7cacdc35a886ef8264eb346f414 and Sha-1 871c992353ec71246e5842d1b86bdefd7865588d You may check it with NirSoft's HasMyFiles.

Comment: Thanks, got it working. It was the checksum, Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

VirtualBox only supports a handful of distros, and on them too there are many issues even after installing the guest addons. Here is the complete list (I don't see Backtrack mentioned anywhere):

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes

Comment: that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yep. Even if the OS is not officially supported, it should at least boot. Either the file was not downloaded properly, or the boot-sequence is not properly set in the VM's settings. Recheck your boot settings to make sure you are booting from the ISO file.